# In Firefox for Android not a single link clicks, it only highlights in grey

Tags: android, html, wordpress, firefox

If you go on my site on Firefox for Android (either a mobile or a tablet) the links either in the menu, or anywhere else for that matter refuse to click, they only highlight in grey as if they're active, but don't actually do anything.

It works fine in Chrome for Android...I can't figure this one out. Help greatly appreciated.

The site is built in Wordpress

[Total Lawn Care link](http://www.total-lawncare.co.uk/)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a missing closing `</div>` tag in the html. I think the div `<div class="gwrapper">` is the one causing the problem. Chrome is smart enough to "guess" where things should be closed and still work correctly but firefox has more strict of standards.

try modifying the html and add the `</div>` where you think it needs to be.

you can go to [W3C validator.org](https://validator.w3.org/)
to check for errors in your html. I used an editor like [Webstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) to help track the problems.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, I added the missing </div> and it doesn't show as an error on https://validator.w3.org/ anymore, but it didn't fix the issue :(

I'm stumped!

Comment: hmmm. I will have to take another look at it to see if I can find anything else

Comment: I found the problem. jquery.nicescroll was on version 3.1.0 and I could see it was graphically glitching in Firefox on Android, so I had a look and updated it to the latest 3.5.0 beta 5. Completely fixed the links issue and fixed the graphical glitching too. weird!

Comment: Nice! I recommend styling your mobile version quite a bit more because its formatting is a little messed up

Comment: Yeah, my css file got messed up, I put it into a css tidy website and it ruined the media queries, I fixed it now.